# dynamic html select boxes need to update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

Ok, so this one is a little confusing. I have select dropdowns that are produced by PHP. It can be 4 selects, or 30 select dropdowns. Then there's option values. Here's what I have so far

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($notes)){ ?>
<select name="milestone" id="milestone[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]">
<option value="Enrollment Date">Enrollment Date</option>
<option value="Discharge Date">Discharge Date</option>
<option value="A/C Start">A/C Start</option>
<option value="Completion Date">Completion Date</option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

If I have 4 select boxes, I might have arrays as follows: milestone[2134], milestone[2222], milestone[225], and milestone[1022]

The array number is the id of the mysql table entry I need to update with the value of that specific select dropdown. I was thinking maybe to use milestone[][id] and loop through that?

Any ideas since there might be 20 select dropdowns?

Thanks!

Comment: a bit confusing.. what is the problem with your approach? where is your code of updating (js)? you seek a nice way to grab your <select> ids to send their selected options above (php)?

Comment: hi im a bit confused, is it 4 `<select>` or 1 `<select>` with 4 `<option>` inside?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the while loop might return 4 selects or 30 selects. the options will always be only the four values. i'm not sure how to process these with php since the array is not milestone[0], milestone[1] and a normal increment. i need to update the mysql db with the corresponding id that is in the brackets of milestone[id]. does this help? thanks so much guys!

Comment: to help clarify, I need to pass a dynamic number of milestone[], the value of it (option from dropdown), and an id that will get updated in a database.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to fetch the values of your options from the database as well as the id ? Then you should to `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_object` function instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`. This function only returns the number of the results while the two above returns the number as well as values.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

First, I had to apply the array to the name of the select like so and set the id value:

```
<select name="milestone[]" class="mstones" id="<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>">
```

Then, with jquery, looped through the class and created created an array with the value being something I can "explode" in php:

```
var milestoneVal = [];
$("select.mstones").each(function(i, selected){
milestoneVal[i] = this.getAttribute('id') + ':' + $(selected).val();
});
```

Then, simple PHP

```
foreach($_POST['milestone'] as $v){
$m=explode(':',$v);
    //db insert
}
```

It was tricky, and I'm sure there's a cleaner solution, but it works for me! Sorry for the poor initial explanation, and hope this helps someone else.